# Android execute function after pressing "Enter" for EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, enter

I have been following the official Android tutorials and somehow am having a problem with [this very simple example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#EditText) to execute a function after pressing "Enter" for an EditText.

I understand what I'm supposed to do and seem to have everything setup properly, but Eclipse is complaining with this line:

```
edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
```

It underlines `setOnKeyListener` with the error:

> The method setOnKeyListener(View.OnKeyListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener(){})

And also underlines `OnKeyListener` with the error:

> The type new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method DialogInterface.OnKeyListener.onKey(DialogInterface, int, KeyEvent)

Perhaps someone can shoot me in the right direction? Before I try other solutions (which I've already found on stackoverflow), I'd really like to figure this out because it has me flustered that something so simple to follow, as an official tutorial, doesn't seem work.

Comment: Something like this?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451374/use-enter-key-on-softkeyboard-instead-of-clicking-button/4451825#4451825

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From what I can see, It looks like you have the wrong import.

Try

```
edittext.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
```

OR add this import

```
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
```

and Remove this one

```
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnKeyListener;
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks for explaining why it didn't work. I'll have to be very careful on my imports from now on :)

Answer (score 51):

To receive a keyboard event, a View **must** have focus. To force this use:

```
edittext.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
edittext.requestFocus();
```

After that continue with the same code in the example:

```
edittext.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
            (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
          // Perform action on key press
          Toast.makeText(HelloFormStuff.this, edittext.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Delete the import statement that has `DialogInterface`, then import the `View.OnKeyListener`.

Comment: Beautiful, thanks very much! That's what I get for learning CTRL+SHFT+O before anything. Thanks to everyone who replied, this site is a fantastic help.