# ListView items focus behaviour

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm trying to create a `ListView` (with custom `CursorAdapter`) of `EditText` items such that `EditTexts` appear uneditable at first and become editable upon long click. Then the user would edit `EditText` contents and `EditText` would save changes to db upon losing focus. However I've run into a really nasty behaviour that prevents me from doing this.

1) I've set my `EditTexts` to `android:focusable="false"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` in XML.

2) I've created an `OnItemLongClickListener` in my `ListActivity` that does the following:

```java
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
    Log.d("NLAc", "longClick called");
    EditText et = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etFolderName);
    et.setFocusable(true);
    et.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    return true;
}
```

3) And when I create views in my adapter I attach the following focus change listener:

```java
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) 
{
    if (hasFocus)
{
    EditText et = (EditText)v;
    Log.d(TAG, "hasFocus true called " + et.getText());
    et.setText("focused");
    et.setSelection(et.length());
}
else
{
    EditText et = (EditText)v;
    Log.d(TAG, "hasFocus false called " + et.getText());
    et.setText("unfocused");
    et.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
            //TODO Save to DB
}
```

}

What happens is that when I long click the very first item I get the following in the log:

`longClick called`

`hasFocus true called item1`

`hasFocus false called focused`

If I remove the line setting focusable to false (`et.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);`) I get another `hasFocus true called unfocused`.
Apparently things go like this:

1) `EditText` gets focus when set focusable

2) `LinearLayour` containing my `ListView` loses focus and calls internal `unFocus()` on all it's children including my `EditText`

3) `EditText` loses focus

4) `EditText` gets focus - for whatever reason now.

This behaviour prevents me from disabling `EditText` upon losing focus or making it unfocusable until the next long click comes through which is what I want.
Can anyone suggest what I may be missing? Or explain this behaviour? Any solutions appreciated.

Comment: are you sure it's a good thing to save the users input this way? you usually have a button to save user's input data and go further along with your data flow. or save it when activity goes onPause() or user leaves an activity. it will save  you a bunch of time and avoid pain as well. just saying...

Comment: I'm thinking about adding a little 'done' button but I was really hoping that I could just save on anything, like losing focus or 'enter' on soft keyboard.

Comment: I understand but I would really recommend looking at http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8868/best-practices-for-uidesign-on-android-usability-ux and of course at http://www.androidpatterns.com and here goes your ENTER soft KB button http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451374/use-enter-key-on-softkeyboard-instead-of-clicking-button

Comment: Thanks for interesting links, but I'm still eager to understand what's going on with focus :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to make some progress by using two views on top of each other. I'm using a TextView for unfocused display, and I hide it and show an EditText instead on long clicked. But that didn't really help at first with ListView's really weird focus handling until I've experimented with `android:descendantFocusability` setting defined for ViewGroups. After I've set it to `ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS` it's behaviour became much more predictable, at least for me.

Comment: On xml,Top View Group writing android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" works charmly

Answer (score 1):

OK. Here is your code. hope it suits your needs or at least that's what I've gotten from your post :)

---

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class EditListActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ll.setLayoutParams(lp1);
        ll.setOrientation(1);
        ListView lv = new ListView(this);
        MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(this, null);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        ll.addView(lv);
        setContentView(ll);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnLongClickListener, View.OnFocusChangeListener {
        private final String TAG = ListActivity.class.getName();
        List<String> stringsarray;
       private Context context;

        public MyListAdapter(Context context, List<String> phonebook) {
            this.stringsarray = new ArrayList<String>();

            this.stringsarray.add("test1");
            this.stringsarray.add("test2");
            this.stringsarray.add("test3");
            Log.d(TAG, "created list adapter");
            this.setContext(context);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return this.stringsarray.size();
        }

        public String getItem(int position) {
            return this.stringsarray.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }


        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LinearLayout rl = new LinearLayout(getContext());

            rl.setOrientation(1);
            EditText text = new EditText(getContext());

            text.setOnLongClickListener(this);
            text.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
            text.setText(this.stringsarray.get(position));

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            text.setFocusable(true);
            rl.addView(text, lp);
            return rl;
        }

        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
            EditText et = (EditText) view;
                et.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{
                        new InputFilter() {
                            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence src, int start,
                                                       int end, Spanned dst, int dstart, int dend) {
                                return src.length() < 1 ? dst.subSequence(dstart, dend) : "";
                            }
                        }
                });
            if (b) {
                Log.d(TAG, "hasFocus true called " + et.getText());
                et.setText("focused");
                et.setSelection(et.length());

            } else {

                Log.d(TAG, "hasFocus false called " + et.getText());
                et.setText("unfocused");
                //TODO Save to DB
            }
        }

        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
            final EditText et = (EditText) view;
            et.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{
                        new InputFilter() {
                            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence src, int start,
                                                       int end, Spanned dst, int dstart, int dend) {
                               return src;
                            }
                        }
                });
            et.setText("editable");
            Log.d(TAG, "on long click called " + et.getText());
            et.requestFocus();
            et.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

            return true;
        }

        public Context getContext() {
            return context;
        }

        public void setContext(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }
    }

}
```

---

have fun.

Comment: Sorry you had to go that far, but it's not what I'm looking for. It's just a list of editable edittexts that can be rotated using simple clicks. I want a listview of edittext that become editable only after you long clicked on one of them.

Comment: that's exactly what it does. have you tried to compile and test it?

Comment: I have updated the code to make up the correct disabling of the editing and showing soft keyboard. It should be fine now. Tested on my phone with 2.2.2 + emulator on 2.3.3

Comment: Well, now your EditTexts are focusable and enabled but can't be edited, not really what I was looking for :)

Comment: If you want them setEnabled(false) it wont work this way - they will be disabled for everything for any clicks or whatsoever. If they are not focusable you will not be able to tap on them again and do your onLongClicks onClicks again. You can play with background images when they're not editable to make a hint for a user. Otherwise you should rethink your design perhaps.