# My Button is always called twice with performClick

Tags: android, android-button

I have a simple code that shows strings in a `TextView` after a button is pressed or when the user press 'Enter'. When the user presses the button all is find, but when the 'enter' is pressed, it calls `performClick()` to call the same function than the button does. But my fonction is always called twice :

```
 private OnKeyListener ChampKeyListener = new OnKeyListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
            {
                recherche.performClick(); // recherche is my button
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    private OnClickListener RechercheListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        //whatever I have tried here it is always called twice

        }
    };
```

How can I stop that. I have seen that I could solve that my going to another `View` or `Activity` but I don't want to use those.

Any hint? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. As there are two actions on press   `KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN` & `KeyEvent.ACTION_UP`
2. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html

Returns `true` if the listener has consumed the event, `false` otherwise.

Try it...

```
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
          {
                if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
                {
                    recherche.performClick(); // recherche is my button
                    return true;
                }


           }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: or better to use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451374/use-enter-key-on-softkeyboard-instead-of-clicking-button/4451825#4451825 to hanlde  KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER as well

Comment: Thanks that solves my problem! And the other tread was useful too!

Answer (score 2):

It could be that the event is fired twice, once when the key is pressed and again when it is released. Try:

```
@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER &&
            event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        recherche.performClick(); // recherche is my button
        return true; // consume event
    }
    return false;
}
```