# How detect character ':' in Android

Tags: android, input, key

I use OnKeyListener for detect input character but I want to detect ':' character, my code is:

```
etStartingFrom.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener(){

public boolean onKey(View arg0, int key, KeyEvent arg2){

    //how detect ':'


    return false;
}
});
```

Comment: Your question is unclear and seems to be answered, check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451374/use-enter-key-on-softkeyboard-instead-of-clicking-button/4451825#4451825

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: How can I validate EditText input?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763022/android-how-can-i-validate-edittext-input)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting keyEvent Listener and you can detect it here.

```
public boolean onKey(View arg0, int key, KeyEvent arg2){

//how detect ':'

 if(keycode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEMICOLON){
               if(event.isShiftPressed ())
                doYourTaskHere();
                return true;
 }
}
```