# Use "OK" key on softkeyboard (numberPassword keyboard) instead of clicking button?

Tags: java, android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I have an `EditText` which InputType is `numberPassword`, and a `Button`"ANYNAME". I'd like to use "OK" key on softkeyboard (numeric keyboard) instead of the `Button`"ANYNAME" to execute a giving function in my code.

[image]

How can I realize that?

Comment: post what you have tried??

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4451825/801369

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 mEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            // call some function
            return false;
        }
    });
```

if you want to change "Done" button title, use:

```
mEditText.setImeActionLabel("OK", KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

Give some proper explanation...!!!

use Toast Message to know Action is performed or Not.