# Android Studio: Button same function as Keycode Enter

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have made a webbrowser application for android (minSdkVersion 21)
It is working fine but I have a little problem with the Keyboard and a button.

Here you can see the app there is a button when I click on GO it loads a page.
But when i click on enter in my keyboard it does nothing.

[image]

I have tried the following:

- KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER
- loadUrl

In my `activity_main.xml`

```
 <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:imeOptions="actionGo"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:text="Go"/>
```

I think there is no problem so far with my `activity_main.xml`

And in my `MainActivity.java` i have:

```
Button button;  
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
```

---

```
     button.setImeActionLabel("", KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);
                     webView.loadUrl("");
                     return true;
```

When i click on enter on my keyboard i want to have the same function as my button "GO" (it needs to load a page)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use "ENTER" key on softkeyboard instead of clicking button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451374/use-enter-key-on-softkeyboard-instead-of-clicking-button)

Comment: Dont think so the other post says instead what i want is that those 2 (button and keyboard key: ENTER load a page)

Comment: The link I sent will active the button when the enter key is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

paste this code. here edit text is editText where your are taking the input.

```
edittext.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE)) {
                //Your Action as go button
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```