# Android keyboard change enter key

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

How can I change `EditText` keyboard enter key like this ?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use "ENTER" key on softkeyboard instead of clicking button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451374/use-enter-key-on-softkeyboard-instead-of-clicking-button)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The solution for me was adding these two lines in the XML of `Edittext`

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
android:inputType="text"
```

Thx everyone.

Answer (score 20):

Android have  **"android:imeOptions"**  to specify the keyboard action button

```
1. android:imeOptions="actionGo"
2. android:imeOptions="actionDone"
3. android:imeOptions="actionNext"
4. android:imeOptions="actionPrevious"
5. android:imeOptions="actionSend"
```

...and more,
you can use based on requirement

Answer (score 6):

Try using **android:imeOptions** with your EditText in your layout file:

```
android:imeOptions="actionGo"
```

Answer (score 2):

use this in your xml where you have define your edittext `android:imeOptions="actionDone"`